# A celebrity you're guaranteed to know

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I'm famous on the largest scale, and by millions I'm considered hot.
> Often confused with a younger male, but young and male I am not.
> I've never offended and nor have lied, that is what I can guarantee.
> But all too often I chose to hide, note you and all have heard of me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Sol.

> I'm famous on the largest scale

> It's pretty big.

> and by millions I'm considered hot.

> It's super duper hot.

> Often confused with a younger male

> Sun and son are homonyms.

> but young and male I am not

> It's pretty old, and ... probably not gendered at all.

> I've never offended and nor have lied, that is what I can guarantee.

> This is a pretty big assumption, but I guess people aren't generally offended by it.

> But all too often I chose to hide

> Cloudy days.

> note you and all have heard of me.

> I'm pretty sure everyone is aware of the big fiery ball of gas in our sky.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your answer is "male" in France.

Comment: @msh210 Sure, I believe that is also feminine in Germany. These are evidence that this guy is not always genderless.

Comment: Also I think there is a play on words in the title that you could add

Comment: Oh, I get it. Because rot13(_gur fha vf n fgne naq n pryroevgl vf n fgne_).

Comment: "I've never offended and nor have lied": probable reference to rot13(gur Oevgvu gnoybvq).

Comment: @WhatsUp We in France have a better view of _him_ than in Germany, so we know better. All is a matter of orientation.

Comment: @xhienne Lol that's so true. Also male in Spain and in Italy, I think.

Comment: rot13("V'z snzbhf ba gur ynetrfg fpnyr" - Va zhfvp "Fby" vf n abgr va gur znwbe fpnyr)